# AsyncTask, doinBackground never finishes

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask

In my code i am getting the data from online MySQL database using json code.
The problem is that the progress dialog in some cases never finishes, just keeps looping without fetching any data ! doesn't always do this, in most cases it works like a charm.

this is the code, any ideas !!!!

```
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllCategories.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("loading all categories");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
    {

        String url_all_categories = "http://www.*****.com/****/****.php";

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_categories,
                "GET", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                categories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATEGORIES);

                for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = categories.getJSONObject(i);
                    id = c.getString(TAG_CID);
                    name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    descAR = c.getString(TAG_DESC_AR);
                    picture = c.getString(TAG_PICTURE);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_CID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DESC_AR, descAR);
                    map.put(TAG_PICTURE, picture);

                    categoriesList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewCategory.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new LazyAdapter(AllCategories.this, categoriesList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: putting log in various critical point will let you know where your problem is. Also don't start activity from background thread

Answer (score 0):

replace  `pDialog.dismiss();`

with

```
 pDialog.cancel();
```

Comment: will do it, but i kind of thought the problem was from the doinbackground, i thought that it didn't reach the onPostExecute method ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int success;//Globally declared
```

Do it inside onPostExecute:

```
 if (success == 1) {


} else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewCategory.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

and

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_CID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DESC_AR, descAR);
                    map.put(TAG_PICTURE, picture);

                    categoriesList.add(map);
```

inside for loop creating problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the context of the ProgressDialog is the calling activity. That is :
   pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllCategories.this);

AllCategories, should be the activity that started the task. Hope this helps